# Powershell registry entries

Tags: powershell, for-loop, registry

I need to add 4 registry keys then under each key add 2 more subkeys. Then in the 8 subkeys add a DWORD and value.

I figured I could use a FOR loop and run through these. The subkeys are all Client and Server and in each subkey "Client" gets one key and "Server" get another. This is so I can script disabling SSLv2, SSLv3, TLS1.0, TLS1.1 across all the windows servers.

I am not sure where to start

Comment: `This is so I can script disabling SSLv2, SSLv3, TLS1.0, TLS1.1 across all the windows servers` I would recommend to use a GPO to do so.

Comment: Good idea I forgot GPO could that. Thanks!